# Is it possible to use log4r ( logger for Ruby ) to send SNMP traps?

Tags: snmp, log4r

Similar loggers - log4j, log4net etc., have "SNMP appenders", cannot find same for log4r

If not log4r, is there an alternative logger for Ruby that has SNMP trap send feature ?